# For loop to obtain sum and mean on np 3d array

Tags: numpy, for-loop, list-comprehension

I have the following array

```
arr = np.array([[[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]], 
                [[7, 8, 9], [10, 11, 12]]])
```

I want to go through each element and sum on axis 0, so I do:

```
lst = []
for x in arr:
    for y in np.sum(x,axis=0):
        lst.append(y)
```

where now the `lst` is

```
[5, 7, 9, 17, 19, 21]
```

However I want the output to be in the following form:

```
[[5, 7, 9], [17, 19, 21]]
```

to then take the mean of its axis 0 namely (5+17)/2 and so on. The final output should look like

```
[11., 13., 15.]
```

I wonder how can I do this? Is it possible to write this whole operation in a compact form as list comprehension?

**Update:** To get the final output I can do:

```
np.mean(np.reshape(lst, (len(arr),-1)),axis=0)
```

Yet I am sure there is a Pythonic way of doing this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
In [5]: arr = np.array([[[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]],
   ...:                 [[7, 8, 9], [10, 11, 12]]])
In [7]: arr
Out[7]: 
array([[[ 1,  2,  3],
        [ 4,  5,  6]],

       [[ 7,  8,  9],
        [10, 11, 12]]])
```

The `for` iterates on the 1st dimension, as though it was a list of arrays:

```
In [8]: for x in arr:print(x)
[[1 2 3]
 [4 5 6]]
[[ 7  8  9]
 [10 11 12]]
```

`list(arr)` also makes a list (but it is slower than `arr.tolist()).

One common way of iterating on other dimensions is to use an index:

```
In [10]: for i in range(2):print(arr[:,i])
[[1 2 3]
 [7 8 9]]
[[ 4  5  6]
 [10 11 12]]
```

You could also transpose the array placing the desired axis first.

But you don't need to iterate

```
In [13]: arr.sum(axis=1)
Out[13]: 
array([[ 5,  7,  9],
       [17, 19, 21]])
In [14]: arr.sum(axis=1).mean(axis=0)
Out[14]: array([11., 13., 15.])
```